# Can not load FIrst person Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to load bimwalk or first person extension onclick event . I have already checked using `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.FirstPerson.FirstPersonExtension()` but it gives that error

> FirstPerson does not exist on Extensions

And I also used `Autodesk.bimwalk` extension but it seems like nothing worked.

Comment: It seems to don't be linked to [tag:minecraft-forge]

Comment: Did you used correct capital letters in your extension call : `Autodesk.BimWalk` ? Also I think the **FirstPerson** extension is called with `Autodesk.FirstPerson`

Answer (score 0):

It is Autodesk.BimWalk

You can go to [this sample](https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io/), on rightside, click on Built-In tab, there you can toggle BimWalk